# Proof help/verification on exercise in Naive Set Theory by Paul Halmos

Tags: set-theory, solution-verification

I am looking for another set of eyes to look over my answer/proof to an exercise in *Naive Set Theory* by Paul Halmos, as I feel that some steps taken in it are unwarranted. At this point in the book Halmos has given us Three axioms stated in english.

> 1. Axiom of Extension. Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements.
> 2. Axiom of Specification. To every set $A$ and to every condition $S(x)$ there corresponds a set $B$ whose elements are exactly those elements $x$ of $A$ for which $S(x)$ holds.
> 3. Axiom of Pairing. For any two sets there exists a set that they both belong to.

For the exercise we are also given a temporary axiom, *"there exists a set"*, with one consequence of this axiom being the existence of the empty set (this is reached by applying specification on this one set, with $S(x)$ being $x\neq x$). Beyond these four axioms, we have no other resources with which to prove our answer. We can not apply some kind of inductive proof either as we have not defined the set of integers at this point. On page 10 the Exercise is then stated

> Consider the sets ∅,{∅},{{∅}},{{{∅}}}, etc.; consider the pairs such as {∅,{∅}}, formed by any two of them; Consider the pairs formed any two such pairs, or else the mixed pairs formed by any singleton and any pair; and proceed so on ad infinitum. 
> Exercise. Are all the sets obtained in this way distinct from one another?

I answer in the affirmative and try and prove it with the following claim.

**Claim:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be any two sets constructed in the described fashion. If $X$ and $Y$ were uniquely constructed, then $X\neq Y$.

**Proof**. We prove the contrapositive. Let $X$ and $Y$ be any two sets constructed in the described fashion and suppose that $X=Y$. The Axiom of Extension tell us that a set is uniquely determined by it's elements, so $X$ and $Y$ are either both singletons or both pairs. We consider two cases.\

If $X$ and $Y$ are singletons, then $X=\{x_1\}$ and $Y=\{y_1\}$ for for some two sets $x_1$ and $y_1$ constructed in the described above manner. Since $X=Y$, the Axiom of Extension tells us that

$$x_1=y_1$$

Again, $x_1$ and $y_1$ are either both singletons or pairs. If they are both singletons the argument applied to $X$ and $Y$ also holds for $x_1$ and $y_1$. If they are both pairs such that $x_1=\{x_2,x_3\}$ and $y_1=\{y_2,y_3\}$ where $x_2, x_3, y_2$ and $y_3$ are all sets described in the above fashion, then we can apply the Axiom of Extension to $x_1$ and $x_2$ (and without loss of generality) suppose that

$$x_2=y_2 \text{ and } x_3=y_3$$

where the same argument applied to $X$ and $Y$ holds for $x_2$ and $y_2$, and for $x_3$ and $y_3$. Now, since the Axiom of Pairing construction does not imply an infinite sequence, we can continue applying the Axiom of Extension to all such "unearthed" sets in the above manner until we have $\varnothing = \varnothing$. And since The Axiom of Extension assures equality among the elements for every such pair, the above argument implies that $X$ and $Y$ were not constructed uniquely.

In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are both pairs such that $X=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $Y=\{b_1,b_2\}$, we apply the Axiom of Extension to $X$ and $Y$ (and without loss of generality) suppose that

$$a_1=b_1\text{ and }a_2=b_2$$

We then apply the earlier argument to the sets $a_1$ and $b_1$, and $a_2$ and $b_2$. $\square$

$\cdots$

My main concern with this proof is that I feel some steps are relying on intuition. Namely, the fact that eventually after repeated use of the Axiom of Extension we will end with $\varnothing = \varnothing$, and that that all elements of all sets being equal proves the sets were not uniquely constructed. I feel these issue stem two-fold. One, we are given a limited toolkit at this point in the book with which to prove this claim, and two, the vague nature of what a "set uniquely constructed in the manner described by Halmos" means. If there are any tips and improvements anyone has that would be great! I would also like to know if people think I am on the right track here with this proof. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the definition of "these sets" in the exercise is external (in the metatheory) and so should the solution of the exercise be.

Comment: @Jonathan . Well said. You can't write a non-inductive formula in the formal Language Of Set Theory that defines either of the two classes  described by Halmos in the two sentences that begin with "Consider ..."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is why I am having trouble making this air tight without some external appeal. If you have any thoughts or suggestions though I'm all ears, as I have to submit this assignment tonight and besides the two comments I have gotten no feedback.